# Your Kindle Needs Repair: battery invalid: -22

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, amazon, hardware, battery

I'm getting a battery error which might just mean low battery:

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/349103/Your+Kindle+needs+repair.+Repair+Code+0.+Version+2588930001

https://www.reddit.com/r/kindle/comments/5a6z6c/your_kindle_need_repair_battery_invalid_22/

Where does that solution come from?  Or, does the invalid battery indicate loose connection?  It's outside warranty, but only a few months old.  Might be within ninety days.  Right now I have it charging but try the suggested empty file trick to see what happens...